# Entity Framework IsUnique and accept Nulls

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I make a Code First property that accepts null values but it's also an `[Index(IsUnique=true)]`?

For example: a passport number should't be repeated, ergo the `IsUnique`, but if the user doesn't insert one, then it defaults to null, so it accepts multiple nulls.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in EF, you might need go back to use raw sql to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since it will not be unique then, you cannot do it that way.
But you can manage it, by attaching a table:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Passport {
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    public string PassportId { get; set; }
}
```

Be aware, that there are countries, which do not allow storing such numbers.